# Ubuntu Studio Top Panel

Tags: panel

Is there a way to change the location of the top panel? I want to put it on the botton of the screen (like the old Windows was).

Can I do it? How?

Greetings & Blessings from Chile!

Juan

Comment: This explains how you can do this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2200046

Comment: BTW ubuntu studio uses the xfce desktop for future reference.

Comment: I tried to do that, but I couldn't put the panel at the botton position. I could put at the right and the left side, only.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I followed the instructions exactly as they are written and I can't seem to place it on the right or left side even if I try. The only way that I know of to get it on the right or left side is to change the setting from horizontal to vertical or deskbar. Did you install gnome or something? Don't install gnome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the top panel. Then, go to **Panel** > **Panel Preferences**.

[image: Step One]

Now, under the **Display** tab, make sure there is **no** check mark in the **Lock Panel** box.

[image: Step Two]

Next, move your mouse to the very top edge of the screen and double click and hold the second click down to "grab" the top panel and bring the panel directly straight down by moving the mouse directly down until it is at the very bottom of the screen.

[image: Step Three]

[image: Done!]

Tested on Ubuntustudio 15.10 upgraded from 15.04.

Comment: Yeah! I got it! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Awesome, don't forget to click the icon to the left to mark this as the accepted answer if this solves the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Install gnome classic to make changes to your bar
First, run this command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Next, run this following command

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```